# Very low frame rate caused by setText method?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, instruments, frame-rate

I'm facing a very big problem with my iOS application and I absolutely don't know how figure it out!
As the title says, I have a very low frame rate during the opening of a window. I decided to work together with the Instruments provided by Xcode and I found out that the problem is caused by a simple text assignment!

Here the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q8Sf9.png

It says that the assignment

```
_WND_subTitle.text = @"TRY"
```

has been run 2185 times. I don't even know where to look at because i'm using the SKNodeLabel Apple's class (no external or dangerous code implementation) and previously I've been used the same assignment to an other class without problem. Any advices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I figure it out what caused my problem:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23624123/3582537

I found the answer by chance! Basically the font name I used was wrong. Now it works using:

```
_WND_subtitle = [[SKLabelNode alloc] initWithFontNamed:@"CCBackBeat-Light"];
```

Comment: do you do that 2158 times as well though?

Comment: No! Now the statement is run just 1 time :)