# SKLabelNode font name spelled wrong, making the program hang

Tags: fonts, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

While I was running my program I noticed at the part of the code where I declared a SKLabelNode and filled out its attributes, the program was hanging there (I knew this due to NSLog statements). What I saw was that I spelled 'Arial' wrong, instead I used, 'Ariel'. I changed it to the correct spelling, and I ran the program again and it ran fine. Would this be the problem which was causing the program to hang?

Comment: Yeap, wrong font name will cause a "lag" http://stackoverflow.com/a/23624123/3402095