# Custom ttf font makes Spritekit's transition slow in SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am having trouble with transition when using custom ttf fonts for spritekit in swift.

I realized that when I use the code below my app gets laggy and slow for only the first time. Are there any way to fix this issue? Are there any examples or tips?

```
let loadLabel =  SKLabelNode(fontNamed:"Silom")

        loadLabel.text = "Loading ....."
        loadLabel.fontSize = 30
        loadLabel.fontColor = SKColor.whiteColor()
        //loadLabel.position = CGPoint(x:self.size.width/2, y: self.size.height/2 )
        loadLabel.zPosition=2
```

Comment: Double check your fontName it might be wrong.
 http://stackoverflow.com/a/23624123/4078517

Comment: Thank you, but the font files name is Silom.ttf .  Does the extension name matter ? How and with what should it match ?

Comment: You do not need extensions. It should match with your font file (everything before .tff)  Have you tried other fonts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed already, if the font name is misspelled, a loading delay can occur. But, the name of the font you pass when creating SKLabelNode **is not necessarily the same as the filename of the font**. You can use Fontbook to find the actual font name or you could do something like this:

```
for family: String in UIFont.familyNames()
{
     print("\(family)")
     for names: String in UIFont.fontNamesForFamilyName(family)
     {
         print("== \(names)")
     }
}
```

After you find a font name, remember to remove this code snippet from your project.

Also, make sure that you have:

- Included your custom font in your application .plist file
- Checked that your font is included as resource in your bundle (Target->Build Phases -> Copy Bundle Resources.

Comment: Thank you Whirlwind ! It helped me !